# solution for driving multiple 7 segment LED display from 3 volt µC

Tags: led, pic, serial, 7segmentdisplay

So I am looking to drive 6 digits worth of 7 segment LED digit display...
I want to use a 3v PIC, the interface IC's that I am finding ([ICM7218AIPI+](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn31/fn3159.pdf) for instance) list voltages like 2-6V, but upon investigation, the 2V is some low power shutdown mode, and require +4v input for serial communication.
So am i barking up the wrong tree, or do I need some sort of charge pumped serial 
IC (or UART) in between?

Comment: Let me know if I linked to the wrong datasheet. That chip has a parallel interface, not a serial one.

Comment: sorry, i just grabbed one out of the matrix that I thought fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the use of external display driver by choosing a PIC with higher pin-count. Driving six 7-segment digits will need 14 extra pins on your PIC. You can multiplex the display in software. Depending on your application you can use a 28 pin PIC (minimum 18 pin PIC that gives you 16 IO) and go higher if your application demands it.

Removing extra variables (like the driver chip) will ease your debugging efforts.

Here (below image) is something that you would need. You just have to add two more displays. You may not need transistors depending on the PIC and display current source and requirements. Make sure you check the current requirements of your display and the current that your PIC can sink.

[image]

Comment: I have considered it... I may very well end up going that way, I wanted an dedicated IC so that I could only have one PIC and drive several of these groups... but 28pin PICs are cheaper at the 1-25 quantity than these IC's so I still may end up going that route.

Comment: I guess i need 6 tri state output pins and 7 ground/+5 pins, is that right?

Comment: @GradyPlayer You don't need tristate pins. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I am accepting because I already have common anode displays and other pics, thank you for the diagram

Comment: Common anode displays are better as the sink capabilities of PICs are greater than source.

Comment: You can use a low pincount PIC and use simple shift registers for port expansion. That way you can drive as many displays you want from just a small PIC.

Comment: I used this same time-multiplexing method for the 7-segment displays on an industrial timer I designed a few years back. We sold thousands of units, and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Maxim makes several low voltage 7-seg LED drivers.  [MAX6958](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/3638) for example.  More [here](http://para.maximintegrated.com/en/search.mvp?fam=disp_driv&397=LED&tree=master).

Comment: I looked at some from maxim... I can use the IC you specified, i just have to re-order common cathode displays, but every other spec would jive.